# Mongo bulk filter and add concatenated field

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a Mongo collection that I'm trying to update (in PyMongo). I have documents like `{'state': 'ny', 'city': 'nyc', 'race': 'b', 'ethnicity': 'h'}` and I'm trying to bulk operate on these documents by matching certain criteria and created a concatenated 'race_ethnicity' field.

A pseudo example might be:

```
filter = {
    'state': 'ny',
    'city': 'nyc',
    'race': {"$exists": True},
    'ethnicity': {"$exists": True},
    'race_ethnicity': {"$exists": False}
}

action = {'$addFields': {'race_ethnicity': {'$concat': ['$race', '$ethnicity']}}}))
```

Using the above document, the updated document would be: `{'state': 'ny', 'city': 'nyc', 'race': 'b', 'ethnicity': 'h', 'race_ethnicity': 'bh'}`.

I want to bulk match, and bulk update a collection like this — how do I go about this without getting a BulkWriteError?

*** What I tried:

```
updates = []
updates.append(UpdateMany({
        'state': 'ny',
        'city': 'nyc',
        "race": {"$exists": True},
        "ethnicity": {"$exists": True},
        "race_ethnicity": {"$exists": False}
    },
    {'$addFields': {'race_ethnicity': {'$concat': ['$race', '$ethnicity']}}}))
self.db.bulk_write(updates)
```

This produced the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your bulk write payload is not correct as per [bulkWrite() syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/),
- `$addFields` is an aggregation pipeline stage you can not use in regular update queries, so to resolve this You can use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

```
updates = []

updates.append({
  'updateMany': {
    'filter': {
      'state': 'ny',
      'city': 'nyc',
      'race': { '$exists': True},
      'ethnicity': { '$exists': True},
      'race_ethnicity': { '$exists': False}
    },
    'update': [
      {
        '$set': { 'race_ethnicity': { '$concat': ['$race', '$ethnicity'] } }
      }
    ]
  }
})

self.db.bulk_write(updates)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I5Ie7Zs4G7T)